# Laravel 7 Remember me function is it correct

Tags: php, laravel

**I searched the internet for how to create a "Remember me" feature.**

**And I found this method and tried it but I'm not sure if it's a good method.**

**Is this a good method for the "remember me" function?**

1. **Mysql table add**

```
remember_token / VAR_CHAR 255
```

2. **signin.blade.php**

**I added this to signin.blade.php**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember_token" id="remember_token"> 
<label style="position:relative; top: 5px;" for="remember">Remember me</label>
```

3.**AcountController.php login part**

**I added this to AccountController.php**

```
$remember_token = ($request->has('remember_token')) ? true : false;
```

```
        if($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::route('account-sign-in')
                   ->withErrors($validator)
                   ->withInput();
        }else{

            $remember_token = ($request->has('remember_token')) ? true : false; // add

            $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
                'email'     => $request->input('email'),
                'password'  => $request->input('password'),
                'active'    => 1
            ),$remember_token); // add

            if($auth){
                return Redirect::intended('/');
            }else{
                return Redirect::route('account-sign-in')
                       ->with('global','Email/Password');
            }
        }
            return Redirect::route('account-sign-in')
                   ->with('global','Your account has not been activated');
    }
```

4.**AccountController.php registration part**

**Add "remember_token => 0" to the registration section**

**We added this so they would not get an error when registering**

```
              $user= User::create(array(
                'email'    => $email,
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => \Hash::make($password),
                'code'     => $code,
                'active'   => 0,
                'remember_token' => 0
            ));
```

5.**User.php**

**I added remember_token to User.php**

```
  protected $fillable = [
        'email','username','password','code','active','remember_token',
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you use is ok but You can also simply use this

```
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Comment: I ask if my method I set above is whether it works properly if you can try it out and let me know